# Cannot access variable from one function to another function in same class

Tags: php, laravel, function

I have a class and I am defining a variable

```
namespace App\System\System;

class BoldSystem
{

    private $clientInfo;

    //I am assigning a new value to clientinfo variable
    public function validateClient($firstname, $lastname, $email, $number)
    {
        $this->clientinfo = "firstname=".$firstname."&lastname=".$lastname."&email=".$email."&number=".$number;
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Now, in the same class, I want to use this new assigned value to `$clientinfo` variable, in another function `complete()`

```
namespace App\System\System;

class BoldSystem
{

    private $clientInfo;

    //The value stored to clientinfo should be accessed from complete function
    public function validateClient($firstname, $lastname, $email, $number)
    {
        $this->clientinfo = "firstname=".$firstname."&lastname=".$lastname."&email=".$email."&number=".$number;
        return 'test';
    }
    //I want to retrieve the value stored to clientinfo in this function
    public function complete()
    {
        return $this->clientinfo;
    }
}
```

When I call `complete()` function I get `null` value, while I am supposed to get `$clientinfo` value from the `validateClient` function.

I am calling the `validateClient` function in a separate class like this

```
class bookAppointment
{

    public function validate()
    {
        $business = new BoldSystem();
        $validate = $business->validateClient('test', 'test', 'test@gmail.com', '519998889898');
    }

    public function book()
    {
        $business = new BoldSystem();
        //this returns null
        $book = $business->complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the code, how you use the instance of BoldSystem (constructur etc...)?

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are creating 2 different instances (in validate and book method of bookAppointment class)! So it should be clear to you, why complete() returns null ;) Maybe you should use a class property for $business.

Not knowing much about your system, you could possibly inject an instance of `BoldSystem` into the constructor of `bookAppointment` like this:

```
class bookAppointment {

    public $business;

    public function __construct(BoldSystem $boldSystem)
    {
        $this->business = $boldSystem;
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $validate = $this->business->validateClient('test', 'test', 'test@gmail.com', '519998889898');
        // ... you further code
    }

    public function book()
    {
        // ...
        $book = $this->business->complete();
        // ...
    }
}
```

It is just an example for holding an instance of `BoldSystem` in `bookAppointment`. Another option would be creating setter/getter methods in `bookAppointment` for the `Boldsystem` property.

Comment: Yeah, i realised that just now

Comment: How can I use the `$business` instance in these two functions in my class?